# How does the reduction of the frame bundle affect the tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a differential manifold and $F(M)$ its frame bundle.

Suppose there is a reduction  of the structure group of $F(M)$ from $GL(m,\mathbb{R})$ to the Lie group $H$ and let $F_{r}(M)$ be the reduced $H$-principal fiber bundle.

My question is:

How does the reduction of $F(M)$ to $F_{r}(M)$ affect the tangent bundle?

I know that the tangent bundle $T(M)$ of $M$ is an associated vector bundle of $F(M)$, and thus I am led to think that the reduction of $F(M)$ will restrict the transition functions of $T(M)$ to "take values" in $H$; now I want to know if the restriction of the transition functions of $T(M)$ is such that the "reduced tangent bundle" $T_{r}(M)$, as a differential manifold, can be seen as a submanifold of $T(M)$.

For clarity the specific example I am interested in is the case:

- $M=\mathbb{R}^{4}$;
- $H=\mathcal{G}=SO(3)\rtimes\mathbb{R}^{3}$, i.e. the homogeneous Galilei group.

Thank You.

Comment: The tangent bundle, as a bundle, has not gotten any smaller; it's only gotten simpler.

Comment: How can You prove it? In the case of the frame bundle $F(M)$ the reduced frame bundle $F_{r}(M)$ is actually a sub-bundle of $F(M)$ (see Kobayashi and Nomizu: foundations of differential geometry vol. 1 pag. 53), so I find it weird that there is no change in $T(M)$, seen now as an associated bundle to $F_{r}(M)$, except for the transition functions.

Comment: There's nothing to prove; there just is no "reduced tangent bundle." For example, suppose $H = 1$. A reduction to $H$ just means a trivialization of the tangent bundle. But that doesn't change anything about the tangent bundle, it just tells you a property of it, namely that it's trivializable. A trivial vector bundle is less interesting than an arbitrary vector bundle but it's still the same size.

Comment: Ok, I really thank You for your kind disponibility, but probably I did not express myself correctly. The tangent bundle $T(M)$ is an associated vector bundle of $F(M)$ where the fiber is an $m$-dimensional vector space $V_{m}$ where $GL(m,\mathbb{R})$ acts. Now if I reduce $GL(m,\mathbb{R})$ to $H$, and thus $F(M)$ to $F_{r}(M)$, and consider the action of $H$ on $V_{m}$, how does look the associated vector bundle of $F_{r}(M)$ with fibre $V_{m}$?

Comment: It's still just the tangent bundle.